# NestJS - ValidationPipe in WebsocketGateway returns Internal Server Error

Tags: typescript, websocket, nestjs

I'm trying to add some validation to my WebSocketGateway in NestJS. Here's the code:

```js
// MessageDTO

import { IsNotEmpty, MinLength } from 'class-validator';

export class MessageDTO {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  @MinLength(10)
  text: string;
}
```

```js
// Gateway

import { ValidationPipe, UsePipes } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessageBody, SubscribeMessage, WebSocketGateway, WsResponse } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { MessageService } from './message/message.service';
import { MessageDTO } from './message/message.dto';
import { Message } from './message/message.entity';

@WebSocketGateway()
export class AppGateway {
  constructor(private readonly messageService: MessageService) {}

  @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  async handleMessage(@MessageBody() dto: MessageDTO): Promise<WsResponse<Message>> {
    const message = await this.messageService.saveMessage(dto);
    return { event: 'message', data: message };
  }
}
```

Now, when I try to send a message that doesn't meet validation rules, it errors out, but the client always receives `{ status: 'error', message: 'Internal server error'}`. Also, Nest logs the error to the console (which I belive should not happen...?):

```sh
thing_api | Error: Bad Request Exception
thing_api |     at ValidationPipe.exceptionFactory (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:78:20)
thing_api |     at ValidationPipe.transform (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/common/pipes/validation.pipe.js:50:24)
thing_api |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:89:5)
thing_api |     at async resolveParamValue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:104:31)
thing_api |     at async Promise.all (index 0)
thing_api |     at async pipesFn (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:106:13)
thing_api |     at async /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-context-creator.js:41:17
thing_api |     at async AppGateway.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/context/ws-proxy.js:11:32)
thing_api |     at async WebSocketsController.pickResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nestjs/websockets/web-sockets-controller.js:85:24)
```

However, if I use the same DTO and validation pipe in regular controller, it works like a charm - with malformed payload I get properly formatted error message. Can somebody point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you find a solution for your problem? I have exactly the same

Answer (score 5):

[`BadRequestException`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/exceptions/bad-request.exception.ts) is a child class of [`HttpException`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/exceptions/http.exception.ts). Nest's default [exception handler for websockets](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/websockets/exceptions/base-ws-exception-filter.ts#L19) checks to see if the caught exception is an `instanceof WsException` and if not returns an unknown exception.

To get around this, you can implement a filter that catches `BadRequestException` and transforms it to an appropriate `WsException` before having Nest's exception filter handle the exception from there.

```js
@Catch(BadRequestException)
export class BadRequestTransformationFilter extends BaseWsExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: BadRequestException, host: ArgumentHost) {
    const properException = new WsException(exception.getResponse());
    super.catch(properException, host);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can rewrite [the default websocket filter](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/8.0.0/packages/websockets/exceptions/base-ws-exception-filter.ts), to catch both http exception and websocket exception.

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, HttpException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { WsException } from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Socket } from 'socket.io';

@Catch(WsException, HttpException)
export class WsExceptionFilter {
  public catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const client = host.switchToWs().getClient();
    this.handleError(client, exception);
  }

  public handleError(client: Socket, exception: HttpException | WsException) {
    if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
      // handle http exception
    } else {
      // handle websocket exception
    }
  }
}
```

Then use it in your gateway

```
@UseFilters(WsExceptionFilter)
@WebSocketGateway()
export class WorkspacesGateway {}
```

Answer (score 2):

ValidationPipe got [exceptionFactory](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe) option so you can just pass a custom factory to it, like:

```
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({
    exceptionFactory(validationErrors = []) {
        if (this.isDetailedOutputDisabled) {
            return new WsException('Bad request');
        }
        const errors = this.flattenValidationErrors(validationErrors);

        return new WsException(errors);
    }
}))
```

Or extend built-in ValidationPipe

```
import {Injectable, ValidationPipe} from '@nestjs/common';
import {WsException} from "@nestjs/websockets";

@Injectable()
export class WSValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe{

  createExceptionFactory() {
    return (validationErrors = []) => {
      if (this.isDetailedOutputDisabled) {
        return new WsException('Bad request');
      }
      const errors = this.flattenValidationErrors(validationErrors);

      return new WsException(errors);
    };
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create my SocketValidation Pipe

```
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { validate } from 'class-validator';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';
import { WsException } from '@nestjs/websockets';

@Injectable()
export class SocketValidationPipe  implements PipeTransform<any> {

  constructor() {
    // super(options)
  }

  async transform(value: any, { metatype }: ArgumentMetadata) {
    if (!metatype || !this.toValidate(metatype)) {
      return value;
    }
    const object = plainToClass(metatype, JSON.parse(value));
    const errors = await validate(object);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      throw new WsException('Wrong message!');//new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
    }
    return value;
  }

  private toValidate(metatype: Function): boolean {
    const types: Function[] = [String, Boolean, Number, Array, Object];
    return !types.includes(metatype);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this code resolves the question?

Answer (score 0):

I overrode the `ValidationPipe` class `transform` method by a custom class extending it and used the custom class instead. 
It looks like this:

```js
export class WSValidationPipe extends ValidationPipe {
  constructor(options?: ValidationPipeOptions) {
    super(options);
  }

  async transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata): Promise<any> {
    try {
      return await super.transform(value, metadata);
    } catch (e: any) {
      if (e instanceof HttpException) {
        throw new WsException(e.getResponse());
      }

      throw e;
    }
  }
}
```